# Does const go before or after CGFloat?

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point, constants, cgfloat

Does it even matter? [Const before or const after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503352/const-before-or-const-after) I'm guessing that whether I put `const` before or after `CGFloat` it makes the value of `CGFloat` constant, but what about the pointer? Is this right for Objective-C:

```
// Example.h

extern CGFloat const kPasscodeInputBoxWidth;


// Example.m

CGFloat const kPasscodeInputBoxWidth = 61.0f;
```

Comment: what about what pointer?

Comment: I mean, the memory address of the value of the `CGFloat`. Does that stay constant?

Comment: `kPasscodeInputBoxWidth` identifies an object (of unqualified type `CGFloat`). That object (as all other objects) `"... exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime ..."` (See 6.2.4/2 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)), so, by definition, the address of the object is constant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It can go either before or after. In the case of a pointer, what matters is whether the `const` ends up before or after the asterisk:

```
const int *a;    // pointer to const int -- can't change what a points at
int const *a;    // same

int *const a;    // const pointer to int -- can't change the pointer itself.
                 // Note: must be initialized, since it can't be assigned.
```

Comment: You can also have `const int *const a;`: a read-only pointer to read-only objects :)

Comment: question relates to CGFloat not integer pointers. For integers, Apple guidelines state "You can use const to create an integer constant if the constant is unrelated to other constants; otherwise, use enumeration.". They only advocate const while using float. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.pdf

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: The exact type (int, long, float, double, CGFloat, etc.) is pretty much irrelevant here.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter (I've always used the former, but I guess it's a matter of style):

```
const CGFloat kPasscodeInputBoxWidth = 61.0;
CGFloat const kPasscodeInputBoxWidth = 61.0;
```

At least in the current rendition of `CGFloat`, it's just a typedef of `double`, so do as you would with a regular primitive datatype. For pointers, the placement of const will determine if it's the pointer or the value that is constant, so for that it does matter.

Comment: `CGFloat` is actually a `float`, not a `double`.

Comment: I think it varies between 32- and 64-bit systems. I run 64-bit and for me it's a double.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. I was just going by line 89 of `CGBase.h`: `typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;`, which I got to by command-clicking on `CGFloat` in Xcode. But, how could the source code be different for you? Shouldn't it be the same on all machines? Hmmm... I thought I was running 64-bit too. How do wou know it's not a `double`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought I had read that somewhere when you said it was float, but it might be double for everyone. It's not like double requires a 64-bit system. They could theoretically be different even though we have the same source code, through preprocessor defines.