# What is the diference between these two declarations:

Tags: c

I am new in C programming and I wondered what is the difference between these two declarations:

```
const int a;
```

and

```
int const a;
```

Both are well accepted by the compiler.

Comment: And the followup to this question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: possible duplicate of [Const before or const after?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503352/const-before-or-const-after) I'm sure people will yell at me saying it's tagged C++, but in this context, it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. Both are same. `int` and `const` both are **declaration specifiers** and they can occur in any order. Grammar says all about it

#### C11: 6.7 Declarations:

> declaration-specifiers:
>
> > storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
> >             **type-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
> >
> >             type-qualifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>**
> >             function-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
> >             alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>

#### C11: 6.7.2 Type specifiers (p2):

> [...] the **type specifiers** may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other **declaration specifiers**.

Comment: I was looking through the standard, but then it was so human-unreadable that I gave up. +1 for finding it.

Answer (score 2):

No difference.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_%28computer_programming%29#Simple_data_types):

> For simple non-pointer data types, applying the `const` qualifier is straightforward. It can go on either side of the type for historical reasons (that is, `const char foo = 'a';` is equivalent to `char const foo = 'a';`). On some implementations, using `const` on both sides of the type (for instance, `const char const`) generates a warning but not an error.

Answer (score 0):

They  are both same. You declared  2  constants  variables.