# Why the object copied to must have the same LOW level of constant as the object copied from?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of keyword const.

My question is why the object copied to (*p in this example) must have the same LOW level constant as the object copied from (p3 in this example).

I understand that they must have the same low level constant in order for the code to be valid, but I don't understand why this is the case.

What is the reason behind it?

```
const int *p2;
const int *const p3 = nullptr;
p2 = p3; //ok
int *p = p3; //error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'const int *const'.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503352/const-before-or-const-after

Comment: You don't really have object copies in your sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use a fictional compiler that accepts the assignment.

```
const int a = 1;

const int *const p3 = &a;
const int *p2 = p3; //ok

int *p = p3; //ok too !

*p = 42;
```

Oops ! We just modified `a`, which was `const`. That's a one-way ticket to UB-Land. This is the reason why you cannot implicitly remove `const` qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Simple and straight to the point! REally appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

there is a great answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const).

your problem is that `const int *` means the int is constant,
and so you cannot give its address to a pointer which points to a non const int.
if he let you do it you would have been able to change the int.
`*p = 5;`
will change a const value.