# How do I return a function pointer as const?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have created a dynamic array `struct Vector` whose internals I keep hidden from users. Instead, functions are provided to interact with them, such as

```
bool Vector_push(struct Vector *vector, const void *value)
```

To help with the popping of elements, the struct holds a pointer to the function that properly deletes each element. This function is set with the function:

```
void Vector_set_type_destructor(struct Vector *vector, void (*type_destructor)(void *))
```

I felt it was a little odd to provide a setter without a getter, so I quickly added the following function.

```
const void (*Vector_type_destructor(const struct Vector *vector))(void *);
```

Notice how I added the `const` keyword, as I wanted the type destructor to only be modifiable through the setter, and not through the returned pointer. However, I received the following warning from clang.

```
src/Vector.c:184:66: warning: function cannot return qualified void type
      'const void' [-Wqualified-void-return-type]
const void (*Vector_type_destructor(const struct Vector *vector))(void *) {
                                                                 ^
src/Vector.c:185:12: warning: incompatible pointer types returning
      'void (*const)(void *)' from a function with result type
      'const void (*)(void *)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    return vector->type_destructor;
```

How do I properly return the pointer `void (*type_destructor)(void *)` through the function without exposing it to possible modification?

Comment: I don't get it. How could a user modify the pointer to the destructor function? First scenario: I call the getter and store the result in a local variable x. Later I modify the content of x. Now the local variable points to a different function. But the function pointer stored in the struct Vector still points to the original function. No problem! Second scenario: I call the getter, store the result in x. Then I dereference x and modify the bytes stored at its address. That is, I modify the code of the destructor function. No sane person would do that. - Which scenario are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Your title asks about a function pointer, the code shows a pointer to `const` and somehow your text seems to ask for a `const` pointer. Also how does `void *` come into play? See [ask], your question is quite misty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting `const` next to the `*` instead:

```
void (*const Vector_type_destructor(const struct Vector *vector))(void *);
```

Comment: The compiler has fallen silent, so this appears to be the correct answer. Could you explain how this is to be read as returning a const pointer of `void (*p)(void *)`?

Comment: I suggest reading up on an article that explains how how type declarations in C are to be read.  For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5503393 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/89100 .

Comment: Thanks. I usually have most of them down, but this one's just a tad nasty.