# c++ - operator trouble - access violation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, access-violation

I am have a few problems with  an access violation in my overload operator for a struct. I realize I'm doing something wrong, and it is most likely a silly mistake, however I am just not sure where that may be.

I have the following:

```
struct Circle
{
    Circle() : innerCircle(nullptr) {}
    Circle * const innerCircle;

    Circle& operator =(Circle *inner)
    {
        innerCircle[0] = inner;    // Exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr.
        return *this;
    }
}

void somefunction(Circle * c)
{
    Circle *c2 = new Circle();
    c->innerCircle[0] = c2;
}
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: What is `node`?

Comment: @Arnav Borborah, haha! My bad, mislabeled.

Comment: You should use a debugger, but it sure look slike `innerCircle` is null so `innerCircle[0]` is UB.

Comment: @aromans *I am just not sure where that may be.* -- Not sure?  So in your own words, describe what this line does: `c->innerCircle[0] = c2;`.

Comment: @Borgleader, I did just find out that mpNext is null. I thought I was assigning it a value. Not sure why it is still null. That is where my problem is! :)

Comment: ...actually you should describe not only that line, but the whole code, because either you misunderstood something or you are trying to implement a very unconventional assignment operator

Comment: P.S: That assignment operator is infinitely recursive...

Comment: @Borgleader I dont think so, because the assigment inside the operator is on pointers

Comment: @tobi303 `Circle& operator =(Circle *inner)` -> `innerCircle[0] = inner;` on the lhs we have Circle& on the rhs Circle*. ([Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6d6c4018c885b8c) link)

Comment: To OP: what do you believe `innerCircle[0]` _means_? If you don't know, why did you add the `[0]`? If you do know, what is it?

Comment: @Borgleader uh right, sorry got confused.

Comment: @Useless, I guess this is kind of my understanding. I have the const pointer to a Circle. So, my pointer cannot change address however the Circle value itself inside the address can change. So my attempt is to change the Circle value inside innerCircle to a different circle

Comment: @aromans The problem with the way youve defined the operator (on top of the null ptr issue) is its infinitely recursive. You call operator= on a circle, which take a Circle* and then attempts to call operator= on its innercircle (which is also a Circle), which will inturn call operator= on *its* innercircle... see where I'm going with this?

Comment: @Borgleader, yeah I see where your going with that. Oops! :P

Comment: @aromans That is an abuse of the assignment operator.  Don't use pointers as arguments.  An assignment operator's job should be just one thing, assign a `Circle` to another existing `Circle`, and that prototype is `Circle& operator=(const Circle&);`.  If you want a function to assign a pointer, then use a different name such as `set_inner_circle` or something similar to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be reasoning about pointers, rather than anything specific to operators.

> I have the const pointer to a Circle. So, my pointer cannot change address

true - whatever object your const pointer is initialized to point to, it can never change to point at some other object instead.

> however the Circle value itself inside the address can change

Yes,*if* your const pointer points to an object, you can mutate the object in-place

> So my attempt is to change the Circle value inside innerCircle

But this assumes `innerCircle` points to an object. You initialized it to `nullptr`, which means it *does not point to any object*. That's what `nullptr` (or the old `NULL`) *means*.

Since your pointer doesn't point at an object, there's nothing there you can legally mutate. Since you declared your pointer `const`, you also can't ever change it to point at a real object.

After that, as borgleader says, you get the recursive definition of circle problem.

Maybe `Circle` should just have a (maybe-nullptr) pointer to circle, which it can mutate to point at a `Circle` if requested? Eg.

```
struct Circle
{
    Circle() : innerCircle(nullptr) {}
    Circle* innerCircle;

    void insert(Circle *inner)
    {
        innerCircle = inner;
    }

    bool hasInner() const { return (innerCircle != nullptr); }
    Circle* getInner() const) { return innerCircle; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object * const obj;        // read right-to-left:  const pointer to Object
Object const * obj;        // read right-to-left:  pointer to const Object
Object const * const obj;  // read right-to-left:  const pointer to const Object
```

Look here

[Const before or const after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503352/const-before-or-const-after)

So you have a constant pointer which is initialized to null in the constructor itself. So You cannot change it later. So in line

```
c->innerCircle[0] = c2;
```

you are getting and will always get a null.