# Passing address of a variable by reference in C++

Tags: c++

```
void test(const int*& in){}

int main(){
 int a = 5; 
 test(&a);
 return 0;
}
```

Above code does not compile saying `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'const int*&' to an rvalue of type 'const int*'`. It does work as expected if I make this change:

```
 int a = 5;
 const int *b = &a; // `const` has to be specified here. why?
 test(b);
```

I have 2 questions:

1- Why doesn't my first example work? if a regular constant can be passed like this:

```
void test(const int& in){}

int main(){
 test(5);
 return 0;
}
```

`5` doesn't have a reference, C++ does the work behind the scene to create a temp variable for me. Why isn't it doing the same in the case of passing a pointer by reference?

2- Why do I have to specify `const` above before `int *b` for it to compile? since I don't have to put it in the case of a regular integer reference? i.e this works fine:

```
void test(const int& in){}

int main(){
 int a = 5;  // no `const` added.
 test(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Above code does not compile saying &a is not a reference" nope. Read the compiler error more carefully and please include it in the quesiton

Comment: I have modified it.

Comment: The subtlety here is that `const int&` is a `const` reference to an `int`, but `const int*&` is a non-`const` reference to a `const int*`, which is itself the type "pointer to `const int`". You can make the latter reference itself `const` by making the argument `const int* const& in`, although there's very little reason to do that instead of just `const int* in` and taking the argument by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- Why doesn't my first example work?

The parameter is a reference to a pointer to const. `&a` - which is the argument - is a pointer to non-const. Pointer to const and pointer to non-const are different types. The argument could be implicitly converted to a pointer to const type. However, the result of that conversion is an rvalue - it is a temporary object. The parameter of the function is an lvalue reference to non-const, and such references cannot be bound to rvalues<sup>1</sup>.

> if a regular constant can be passed like this:

In that example, you have an lvalue reference to const. Lvalue references to const can be bound to rvalues. In the case of `test(a)`, the type of the referred object even matches with the type of the reference, so there isn't even a conversion and parameter refers directly to the passed argument.

> Why isn't it doing the same in the case of passing a pointer by reference?

See <sup>1</sup> above

> Why do I have to specify const above before int *b for it to compile?

Because the parameter is an lvalue reference to non-const pointer to const. If you don't specify const there, then you have a pointer to non-const, and thus you would need a conversion such as in the case of `&a` and thus the result would be an rvalue and thus the lvalue reference to non-const cannot be bound.

You could make the pointer function analogous to the integer example by using a reference to const that matches with the type of the argument:

```
int* a;

// analogous to your int example:
void test1(int* const& in);
test1(&a); // OK, no conversion

// now, we have a reference to non-const,
// but that's fine since there is no conversion:
void test2(int* const& in);
test2(&a); // OK, no conversion

// now there is conversion, but that's fine since
// it is an lvalue reference to const:
void test3(const int* const& in); 
test3(&a); // OK, conversion

// there's a conversion here and the reference isn't
// const but that's fine since it's an rvalue reference:
void test4(const int*&& in); 
test4(&a); // OK, conversion
```

Or, you could make the integer example fail by making it analogous to the pointer example by introducing a conversion and by using a reference to non-const:

```
long b;

// analogous to your pointer example:
void test5(int& in);
test5(b); // NOT OK
```

Note that whether the referred type is a pointer to const or pointer to non-const is entirely separate from the reference being a reference to const or non-const.

Answer (score 0):

(you already have an answer, but I wanted to phrase it differently)

You just fell victim to the [left const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503352/const-before-or-const-after) (aka. west const)!

I assume you know by now that you can make a const-lref to a temporary value, but not a regular lref. This is just the language protecting you from easy typos that would be a pain to find.

```
void test(const int*& in)
```

This function takes an lvalue reference to a nonconst pointer to a const integer. That means `test(&a);` would be attempting to convert a temporary pointer (to const int) to a lvalue reference to a pointer (to const int), which is illegal. It is the equivalent of:

```
void test(int& in) {}
test(5);
```

If you want to pass a temporary pointer to the function, you have to declare the (reference to) the pointer itself to be constant.

```
void test(const int*const & in)
```

Now that you know this, the answer to your second question should be simple as well. Imagine what could happen if you passed a pointer-to-nonconst to your function.

```
const int globalInt = 0; // This variable cannot be modified

void test(const int*& in) {
    in = &globalInt; // This is possible since the pointer will point to a const int... right?
}

int main() {
    int* ptr; // Pointer to a nonconst int
    test(ptr); // If this function could take this argument...
    
    // Later...

    *ptr = 5; // This is legal because the pointer is nonconst...
              // But it somehow carries the address of globalInt. Oh no.
}
```

Comment: Seems like the compiler behaviour gets specific when `references` and `pointers` are mixed, done to avoid issues like you explained.