# function returning const pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants, const-pointer

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    int* i = nullptr;
    int* const X()
    {
        return i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test c;

    int x = 2;
    
    c.i = c.X();
    c.i = &x;
    *c.i += 2;

}
```

what does the **const** change in the `int* const X()` function? in my understanding it should return a const pointer so I shouldn't be able to change what it is pointing to. But I initialize **i** as a non-const pointer `int* i = nullptr;` so I can still do something like `c.i = &x`. I could delete the const from the function and the code would run the exact same way as before.

To prevent changing *pointing-to* value of **i** I would have to initialize **i** as const-pointer `int* const i = nullptr;` like this, but then if I would delete const from the function it still wouldn't change anything anyway. So what's the point of declaring a function that returns a const pointer if it doesn't change anything?

Comment: Returning const pointer is mostly as useful as returning `const int`.

Comment: Returning `const int*`(/`int const*`) would be useful though.

Comment: @Jarod42 so what's the point of returning int* const? is it only for better code readability?

Comment: I don't see any reason to return `int* const` (and it doesn't increase code readability IMO).

Comment: `const` in return type may be used to force copying of an object, but it's useless for trivial types such as pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write the "const" before the type.
Note that the position of const specifies what is going to be constant.
The code below creates a const pointer to a variable value in certain location. (This is what you did in the function)

```
   int* const  ptr;
```

And the code below makes what you want; a pointer to a const value in certain location

```
    const int* ptr;
```

Applied to your code, it would mean:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    const int* i = nullptr;
    const int* X()
    {
        return i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test c;

    int x = 2;
    
    c.i = c.X();
    c.i = &x;
    *c.i += 2;

}
```

If you try this, you will notice the compiler will tell you in the last line that "the expression "*c.i" must be modifiable".

Comment: `You just have to write the "const" before the type.` - More precisely, you just have to write the `const` before the asterisk `*`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5503393