# go through map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, element

So, I have an `std::map<int, my_vector>` and I want to go through each int and analyse the vector.
I haven't gotten to the part of analyzing the vector just yet, I'm still trying to figure out how to go through every single element on the map.
I know it is possible to have an iterator, but I didn't quite understood how it works, also, I don't know if there isn't a better way to do what I intend to do

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4844904/1410711) might be helpful....

Answer (score 6):

You can simply iterate over the map. Each map element is an `std::pair<key, mapped_type>`, so `first` gives you the key, `second` the element.

```
std::map<int, my_vector> m = ....;
for (std::map<int, my_vector>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
  //it-->first gives you the key (int)
  //it->second gives you the mapped element (vector)
}

// C++11 range based for loop
for (const auto& elem : m)
{
  //elem.first gives you the key (int)
  //elem.second gives you the mapped element (vector)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are the perfect thing for this. Look around http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/