# 3D Hash with no collisions on close values

Tags: c++, vector, hash, 3d, collision

I need a hash function for 3D vectors with no collisions between close key values.

The key is a 3d vector of integers. I want no collisions within roughly a 64 * 64 * 64 "area" or larger.

Does anyone know of any hashing functions suited for this purpose, or even better, how would you go about designing a hash for this?

If it's necessary to know, I will be implementing it in C++.

Comment: Why not create a `Map<int,Map<int,Map<int,Object>>>` for your objects? where each int is x,y,z or whatever you're labeling your axis. Or use `double` if you need float values.

Comment: Nice solution but it leads to some rather complicated code - this is how you insert an element: auto it1 = map.insert(std::make_pair(x, std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, Object>>())).first;

auto it2 = it1->second.insert(std::make_pair(y, std::unordered_map<int, Object>())).first;

it2->second.insert(std::make_pair(z, Object()));

Comment: I would have done that a bit differently check the answer I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a `Map<int,Map<int,Map<int,Object>>>` for your objects? Where each `int` is x,y,z or whatever you're labeling your axis.

Here's an example of how you could use it.

```
int x,y,z;
map<int,map<int,map<int,string>>> Vectors = map<int,map<int,map<int,string>>>();
/*give x, y and z a real value*/
Vectors[x][y][z] = "value";
/*more code*/
string ValueAtXYZ = Vectors[x][y][z];
```

Just to explain because its not super obvious.

The `Vectors[x]` returns a `map<int,map<int,string>>`.

I then immediately use that maps `[]` operator with `[y]`.

That then returns (you guessed it) a `map<int,string>`.

I immediately use that maps `[]` operator with `[z]` and can now set the string.

**Note:** Just be sure to loop through it using iterates and not a `for(int x = 0; /*bad code*/;x++)` loop because `[]` adds an element at every location it's used to look up. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844904/839501) an example of a loop and [Here's](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) and example of an unexpected add.

**Edit:**

If you want to make sure that you're not overriding an existing value you could do this.

```
string saveOldValue;
if(Vectors[x][y][z] != ""/*this is the default value of a string*/)
{
    /*There was a string in that vector so store the old Value*/
    saveOldValue = Vectors[x][y][z];        
}

Vectors[x][y][z] = "Value";
```

If you use `[]` on a key that isn't in the map the map creates a default object there. For strings this would be the empty string `""`.

**Or**

```
if(     Vectors.find(x)!=Vectors.end() 
     && Vectors[x].find(y)!=Vectors[x].end() 
     && Vectors[x][y].find(z)!=Vectors[x][y].end())
{
   /* Vectors[x][y][z] has something in it*/
}else
{
   /*Theres nothing at Vectors[x][y][z] so go for it*/
   Vectors[x][y][z] ="value";

}
```

This uses the `find(value)` function which returns an iterator to the location of the key "value" **OR** and iterator that points to `map::end()` if that key is not int the current map.

If you don't have a default value for your thing being stored then use the second check to do your inserts. This greatly increases the useability of this answer and unclutters your code.

The `insert` function has it's place but in this example it would be very hard to use.

Comment: Except I still use `insert` because in my case I do not want to overwrite if it already exists.

Comment: @Brett check the Edit I just added I think it will make your life easier.