# Iterating map of vectors of different sizes in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

So I declared the following map in C++:

```
typedef vector<Vector2D> stackPoints; 
typedef map<int, stackPoints> mapPoints; 
mapPoints drawingPoints;
```

After adding values to it, I want to output all the elements in it, but the vectors at the different key positions are not of the same size:

I am using the following two for-loops that don't work. Sometimes the program crashes at runtime and gives me the out of range vector error.

```
for (int j = 0; j < drawingPoints.size(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < drawingPoints[j].size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "(...)" << endl
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the inner for-loop has the be went through a constant amount of times, as if the following scenario wasn't possible:

1) The first vector has a size of 1, so the inner for-loop will be executed once.

2) Then the second vector of the map has a size of 5 and now I want the for-loop to be went through 5 times, but this seems to not work.

** Edit **

I am using the integer key as a counter, so I increment it by 1 when I add another pair.

Comment: `drawingPoints[j]` gets the entry with key `j`, not the `j`-th entry!

Comment: Yeah, that is what I want, isn't it? Depending on the size of the vector at drawingPoints[ j ] - which changes! - I want the inner for-loop to be executed just as often.

Comment: For your edit, if the int is just an index indicating the number of entries, why not just use a `std::vector<stackPoints>`. Then you can do exactly what you have done.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right, my bad ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple reasons you should be using an iterator.

1. Your map may not contain every element from 0 to `drawingPoints.size()` and for each element that it doesnt contain when you loop over it you will create it.
2. Your highest entry may be greater then `drawingPoints.size()` in which case you will never reach it.

Lets look at outer most loop, if you want to define an iterator for it you should do the following:

```
for (mapPoints::Iterator it = drawingPoints.begin(); it != drawingPoints.end(); it++) {
```

This creates an iterator which you can look at (by doing `it->` or `*it`).

More information can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: I was about to add an answer to suggesting using an iterator when working with maps but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int j = 0; j < drawingPoints.size(); j++)
{
    // This is wrong.
    // j is not necessarily a valid key in the map.
    for (int i = 0; i < drawingPoints[j].size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "(...)" << endl
    }
}
```

Use iterators to avoid such issues.

```
mapPoints::iterator map_begin = drawingPoints.begin();
mapPoints::iterator map_end = drawingPoints.end();
for ( ; map_begin != map_end; ++map_iter )
{
   stackPoints::iterator v_iter = map_iter->second.begin();
   stackPoints::iterator v_end = map_iter->second.end();
   for ( ; v_iter != v_end; ++v_iter )
   {
      cout << "(...)" << endl
   }
}
```

If you are using a C++11 compiler, you can use:

```
for ( auto& map_item : mapPoints )
{
   for ( auto& v_item : map_item.second )
   {
      cout << "(...)" << endl
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is iterating the map: the fact that you can do `drawingPoints[j]` is entirely by accident - the type of your map's key just happens to be `int`, so `j` works fine as its index. However, not all `j`s are going to have anything in the map, so the code does not work.

Here is how you iterate over your map:

```
for(auto& kvp : drawingPoints) {
    cout << "Key " << kvp.first << " has the following values:" << endl;
    for (auto n : kvp.second) {
        cout << n << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The example above requires C++11. If you use an older compiler, use [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844904/335858) to go over a map using iterators.

Comment: I am using the integer key as a counter, so I increment it by 1 when I add another pair.

Comment: @huzzm exactly, it adds another pair, unless the key happens to be there, in which case you iterate over its corresponding vector.

Comment: @huzzm Yes, it would work. However, if the key is always there when you iterate sequentially, then you are better off with a vector of vectors, because vectors are generally faster and take less memory than a map.