# gdb taking a long time and running out of memory

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to trace a segfault using GDB but it's taking an abnormally long time and it runs out of memory before it reaches the segfault.

If I run the program, it takes <1sec to return a segmentation fault like so:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I run it in GDB and let it go, it keeps running for several minutes before using up nearly 4GB of memory and crashing. I currently just started it and checked task manager and it's already using over a gigabyte. I periodically hit Ctrl+C to see what's doing and it looks like it's going through the program but very slowly.

I'm aware that GDB would typically use up more memory but this is a very small program for a college class and it shouldn't be using anywhere close to 4GBs of memory. I'm running this using Bash for Windows but I don't think that's the issue because I tried running it on the school's server and it's taking just as long.

The printout of the cerr statements is:

```
Robert Rose 3  
Load cards start.  
Birmingham Oranges 38  
38  
Begin CO  
Oranges
```

I don't know if this is a problem with my code or with gdb. Here's the repository with all the code: https://github.com/RobRoseKnows/umbc-cs341/tree/master/Projects/Project%202 You can run it with `make test`, `resultsexpected.txt` is not relevant for the testing driver.

The most recent thing I changed was the `loadCards()` method in `Game.cpp`:

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<istream>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;


Game::~Game() {
    while(!m_drawPile.empty()) {
        delete m_drawPile.top();
        m_drawPile.pop();
    }
}


void Game::runSimulation(int players, Player::STRATEGY strategy) {

}



void Game::printDrawPile(ofstream& fileStream) {

    fileStream << "---------- Draw Pile ----------" << endl;

    stack<Card*> drawPileCopy = m_drawPile;

    while(!drawPileCopy.empty()) {

        Card* top = drawPileCopy.top();
        drawPileCopy.pop();

        top->printCard(fileStream);

    }
}



void Game::printResults(ofstream& fileStream) {

}



void Game::loadCards(string filename) {

    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open(filename.c_str(), fileIn.in);

    cerr << "Load cards start." << endl;

    while(!fileIn.eof()) {

        Card* newCard = new Card;

        // Get the string representations of each of the values.
        string dest;
        string commName;
        string payStr;

        fileIn >> dest;
        fileIn >> commName;
        fileIn >> payStr;

        cerr << dest << " " << commName << " " << payStr << endl;

        int pay;
        istringstream(payStr) >> pay;

        cerr << pay << endl;

        Objective* newObjective = createObjective(dest, commName, pay);

        cerr << newObjective->getCommodity()->getName() << " to "
                << newObjective->getDestination() << " for "
                << newObjective->getPayoff() << endl;

        newCard->addObjective(newObjective);

        m_drawPile.push(newCard);

    }

    fileIn.close();

    cerr << "Load cards end." << endl;

}


Objective* Game::createObjective(string dest, string commName, int pay) {

    cerr << "Begin CO" << endl;

    Commodity* commodity = m_bank.getCommodity(commName);

    cerr << commodity->getName();

    return new Objective(dest, commodity, pay);

}
```

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Player.h"
#include "CommodityStore.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include "Objective.h"

class Game {
public:

    ~Game();

    void runSimulation(int players, Player::STRATEGY strategy);

    void printDrawPile(ofstream& fileStream);

    void printResults(ofstream& fileStream);

    void loadCards(string filename);

private:

    stack<Card*> m_drawPile;
    vector<Player*> m_players;
    CommodityStore m_bank;

    Objective* createObjective(string dest, string commName, int pay);

};
#endif
```

And here are some of the files referenced in that function:

**Objective.cpp**

```
#include "Objective.h"
#include "Commodity.h"

#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

Objective::Objective(string dest, Commodity* comm, int pay) {
    m_sDestination = dest;
    m_pCommodity = comm;
    m_iPayoff = pay;
}

// Delete the dynamic memory.
Objective::~Objective() {
    m_pCommodity = NULL;
}

// Prints the objective out to the ofstream.
// Prints in the format: "<commodity> to <destination> for <payoff>"
void Objective::printObjective(ofstream & fileStream) {
    fileStream << m_pCommodity->getName() << " to " << m_sDestination << " for " << m_iPayoff << endl;
}
```

**Objective.h**

```
#ifndef OBJECTIVE_H_
#define OBJECTIVE_H_

#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

class Commodity;

class Objective {
public:
    // Constructor that takes destination, commodity and payoff.
    Objective(string dest, Commodity* comm, int pay);
    // Deconstructor
    ~Objective();

    // Prints the objective to an ofsteam.
    // Prints in the format: "<commodity> to <destination> for <payoff>"
    void printObjective(ofstream & fileStream);


    /* Implement Getters in the header file */
    // Return the destination.
    string getDestination() const {
        return m_sDestination;
    }

    // Returns the pointer to a commodity.
    Commodity* getCommodity() const {
        return m_pCommodity;
    }

    // Returns the payoff for this objective.
    int getPayoff() const {
        return m_iPayoff;
    }
private:
    string m_sDestination;
    Commodity* m_pCommodity;
    int m_iPayoff;
};
#endif
```

**CommodityStore.cpp**

I put a breakpoint near the bottom of the file (marked the line in comments) because I thought that was where the error could be. I was going to check the size of the map once the debugger reached that point but it never did.

```
#include "CommodityStore.h"

#include<fstream>
#include<istream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


CommodityStore::~CommodityStore() {

    // Special thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4844904/1021259 for this line:
    typedef map<string, Commodity*>::iterator it_type;

    for(it_type itr = m_store.begin(); itr != m_store.end(); itr++) {

        // I originally had it deleting the itr->second but that didn't work so now I'm
        // using the iterator to get the key rather than than the object.
        delete m_store[itr->first];

    }

}



// loadCommodities()
// Takes a filename and inserts the commodities in the file into the map.
void CommodityStore::loadCommodities(string filename) {

    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open(filename.c_str(), fileIn.in);


    while(!fileIn.eof()) {

        string commodityName;
        string commodityColor;

        fileIn >> commodityName;
        fileIn >> commodityColor;

//        cerr << commodityName << " " << commodityColor << endl;

        // Create the new commodity and add it to the map.
        Commodity* newComm = new Commodity(commodityName, commodityColor);
        m_store[commodityName] = newComm;
    }

    fileIn.close();

    // Special thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/1021259
}



void CommodityStore::printCommodities(ofstream& fileStream) {

    fileStream << "---------- Commodities ----------" << endl;

    // Special thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4844904/1021259 for this line:
    typedef map<string, Commodity*>::iterator it_type;

    for(it_type itr = m_store.begin(); itr != m_store.end(); itr++) {

        Commodity* on = m_store[itr->first];

        fileStream << on->getName() << " " << on->colorToString(on->getColor()) << endl;

    }

    fileStream << "--------------------------" << endl;
}

Commodity* CommodityStore::getCommodity(string name) {
    cerr << name << endl;      // <<<<<<<<<<< THIS IS WHERE I PUT A BREAKPOINT
    return m_store[name];
}
```

**CommodityStore.h**

```
#ifndef CS_H_
#define CS_H_

#include "Commodity.h"

#include<map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class CommodityStore {
public:


    ~CommodityStore();

    /****
     * Name: loadCommodities()
     * PreCondition:    Requires a list of commodities with name and color on the same line delimited
     *                  by a space. Each one should only be one word long. Different commodities
     *                  should be on different lines.
     * PostCondition:   All the commodities in the given file should now be in the map m_store.
     **/
    void loadCommodities(string filename);

    // This is for testing only.
    void printCommodities(ofstream& fileStream);

    Commodity* getCommodity(string name) ;
private:
    map<string, Commodity*> m_store;
};
#endif
```

**Driver.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#include "Game.h"
#include "CommodityStore.h"

void printGreeting();

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printGreeting();

    string cardFileName = "";
    string commodFileName = "";
//    string playerFileName = "";
//    string strat = "";

    if(argc >= 2) {
        cardFileName = argv[1];
        commodFileName = argv[2];
//        playerFileName = argv[3];
//        strat = argv[4];
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Not enough arguments." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    CommodityStore store = CommodityStore();
    Game game = Game();

    store.loadCommodities(commodFileName);
    game.loadCards(cardFileName);

    ofstream fileOut;

    fileOut.open("results.txt", fileOut.out);

    store.printCommodities(fileOut);
    game.printDrawPile(fileOut);

    fileOut.close();

}

void printGreeting() {
    std::cerr << "Robert Rose 3" << endl;
}
```

**Valgrind Output:**

```
[robrose2@linux1 PROJ2]make val CARDS=cards.txt COMMODITIES=commodities.txt
valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./a.out cards.txt commodities.txt
==16914== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16914== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16914== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16914== Command: ./a.out cards.txt commodities.txt
==16914==
--16914-- Valgrind options:
--16914--    --leak-check=full
--16914--    -v
--16914-- Contents of /proc/version:
--16914--   Linux version 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Aug 23 19:58:13 UTC 2016
--16914-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, amd64-sse3-cx16-avx
--16914-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--16914-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib64/valgrind
--16914-- Reading syms from /afs/umbc.edu/users/r/o/robrose2/home/CMSC341/PROJ2/a.out
--16914-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--16914--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--16914-- Reading syms from /lib64/ld-2.12.so
--16914-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--16914-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib64/valgrind/default.supp
==16914== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-16914-by-robrose2-on-linux1.gl.umbc.edu
==16914== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-16914-by-robrose2-on-linux1.gl.umbc.edu
==16914== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-16914-by-robrose2-on-linux1.gl.umbc.edu
==16914==
==16914== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==16914== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==16914== or are doing some strange experiment):
==16914==   /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=16914 ...command...
==16914==
==16914== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==16914==   /path/to/gdb ./a.out
==16914== and then give GDB the following command
==16914==   target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=16914
==16914== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==16914==
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6617d10 (strlen) redirected to 0x38049551 (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--16914-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--16914-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6617b20 (index) redirected to 0x4a07c30 (index)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6617ba0 (strcmp) redirected to 0x4a08570 (strcmp)
--16914-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
--16914--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--16914-- Reading syms from /lib64/libm-2.12.so
--16914-- Reading syms from /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
--16914--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--16914-- Reading syms from /lib64/libc-2.12.so
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a84e60 (strcasecmp) redirected to 0x480155c (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a87120 (strncasecmp) redirected to 0x480155c (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a82dd0 (__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4a07ab0 (__GI_strrchr)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a812f0 (__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4a07fb0 (__GI_strlen)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a7f870 (strcmp) redirected to 0x480155c (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6b28550 (__strcmp_sse42) redirected to 0x4a084d0 (strcmp)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a812b0 (strlen) redirected to 0x480155c (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6b33820 (__strlen_sse42) redirected to 0x4a07f90 (strlen)
Robert Rose 3--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a89800 (memcpy) redirected to 0x4a08b60 (memcpy)

3
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39dd6bd0a0 (operator new(unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4a0757a (operator new(unsigned long))
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39dd6bb2f0 (operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x4a05f8f (operator delete(void*))
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a7aba0 (malloc) redirected to 0x4a069ac (malloc)
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39dd6bd1d0 (operator new[](unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4a07110 (operator new[](unsigned long))
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39dd6bb330 (operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4a05adf (operator delete[](void*))
--16914-- REDIR: 0x39d6a7ba00 (free) redirected to 0x4a063a9 (free)
Load cards start.
Birmingham Oranges 38
38
Oranges
Begin CO
Oranges
==16914== Invalid read of size 8
==16914==    at 0x39DD69D258: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x4040BF: Commodity::getName() const (Commodity.h:48)
==16914==    by 0x403F4E: Game::createObjective(std::string, std::string, int) (Game.cpp:112)
==16914==    by 0x403C56: Game::loadCards(std::string) (Game.cpp:87)
==16914==    by 0x401D11: main (Driver.cpp:44)
==16914==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==16914==
==16914==
==16914== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==16914==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==16914==    at 0x39DD69D258: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x4040BF: Commodity::getName() const (Commodity.h:48)
==16914==    by 0x403F4E: Game::createObjective(std::string, std::string, int) (Game.cpp:112)
==16914==    by 0x403C56: Game::loadCards(std::string) (Game.cpp:87)
==16914==    by 0x401D11: main (Driver.cpp:44)
==16914==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==16914==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==16914==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==16914==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==16914==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==16914==
==16914== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16914==     in use at exit: 12,381 bytes in 100 blocks
==16914==   total heap usage: 134 allocs, 34 frees, 22,616 bytes allocated
==16914==
==16914== Searching for pointers to 100 not-freed blocks
==16914== Checked 184,744 bytes
==16914==
==16914== 27 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 16
==16914==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D19A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D5EB: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D867: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD67AF8D: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x403AC3: Game::loadCards(std::string) (Game.cpp:76)
==16914==    by 0x401D11: main (Driver.cpp:44)
==16914==
==16914== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 16
==16914==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D19A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D5EB: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D867: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD67AF8D: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x403AAA: Game::loadCards(std::string) (Game.cpp:75)
==16914==    by 0x401D11: main (Driver.cpp:44)
==16914==
==16914== 34 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 16
==16914==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69DDA9: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69DF6B: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x401BF1: main (Driver.cpp:31)
==16914==
==16914== 35 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 16
==16914==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D19A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D5EB: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D867: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD67AF8D: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x403A91: Game::loadCards(std::string) (Game.cpp:74)
==16914==    by 0x401D11: main (Driver.cpp:44)
==16914==
==16914== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 6 of 16
==16914==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69DDA9: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69DF6B: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x401C0E: main (Driver.cpp:32)
==16914==
==16914== 885 bytes in 29 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 14 of 16
==16914==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D19A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D5EB: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD69D867: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x39DD67AF8D: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x404B66: CommodityStore::loadCommodities(std::string) (CommodityStore.cpp:51)
==16914==    by 0x401CBE: main (Driver.cpp:43)
==16914==
==16914== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16914==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16914==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16914==      possibly lost: 1,053 bytes in 34 blocks
==16914==    still reachable: 11,328 bytes in 66 blocks
==16914==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16914== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==16914== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==16914==
==16914== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
==16914==
==16914== 1 errors in context 1 of 7:
==16914== Invalid read of size 8
==16914==    at 0x39DD69D258: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==16914==    by 0x4040BF: Commodity::getName() const (Commodity.h:48)
==16914==    by 0x403F4E: Game::createObjective(std::string, std::string, int) (Game.cpp:112)
==16914==    by 0x403C56: Game::loadCards(std::string) (Game.cpp:87)
==16914==    by 0x401D11: main (Driver.cpp:44)
==16914==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==16914==
--16914--
--16914-- used_suppression:      4 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
--16914-- used_suppression:      2 glibc-2.5.x-on-SUSE-10.2-(PPC)-2a
==16914==
==16914== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
make: *** [val] Segmentation fault
[robrose2@linux1 PROJ2]
```

Comment: Have you run `valgrind` on your code?

Comment: Added the valgrind output. I'm not sure what it means now. I guess the question has changed.

Comment: Sorry, where is the valgrind output?

Comment: Sorry, refresh.

Comment: You might have infinite recursion somewhere..

Comment: You're trying to access an undefined pointer somewhere, by the looks of it (which would explain the segfault)