# Whats the name of this looping map type CPP

Tags: c++

I know it is a dummy question and im gonna get alot of minuses, but its importent to me to know, so I will ask anyway..

I sow the next looping type on map:

```
 for(auto const& ent2 : ent1.second) {
    // ent2.first is the second key
    // ent2.second is the data
  }
```

With this I can loop a map by its iterators easily.
But I want to know if I can use this kind of looping on other kind of data like strings and vectors etc...
Whats the name of this looping kind so I can search on it.

Comment: ***But I want to know if I can use this kind of looping on other kind of data like strings and vectors etc*** Yes you can use range for on other containers.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: If you found the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27344958/4342498) I went ahead and edited the relevant information into the answer so it contains that information.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thank you vary much! its what I nedded...

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you too! it was hellped me also :)